# Dúvida sobre autoload php

Tags: php, php-7, php-autoload

Sobre autoload estudei sobre:

Autoload para classes na mesma pasta

```
function __autoload($nomeClass) {
require_once ("$nomeClass.php");
  }
```

Autoload para classes em pastas especificas

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($nomeClass) {
    if (file_exists("Classes".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$nomeClass.".php") === true) {
        require_once ("Classes".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$nomeClass.".php");
    }
});
```

Como eu faria para que o autoload funcionasse não apenas dentro da pasta "classes" mais ele carregar qualquer classe chamada em qualquer parte do projeto, como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

O ideal é seguir os padrões do PHP.

[PSR-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) *Foi descontinuada, mas vale a pena a leitura*

[PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) *Em uso*

Com essas recomendações você irá se informar mais sobre o uso de `namespace`.

Basicamente as `namespace` são agrupamentos de classes, interfaces, etc. Um dos principais objetivos é evitar conflitos. Com isso você pode passar todo o caminho da classe e o utilizar o `spl_autoload_register` para incluir em seu projeto.

**index.php**

```
define("PATH", __DIR__."/vendor/");

/* Namespace + Nome da class */
use Path\Foo\Bar\MyClass;

spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    $class = str_replace("\\", "/", $class);

    if (file_exists(PATH.$class.".php")) {
        require_once PATH.$class.".php";
    }
});


$cls = new MyClass();
$cls->e();
```

> Dessa forma o "spl_autoload_register" irá buscar o arquivo /vendor/Path/Foo/Bar/MyClass.php

**MyClass.php**

```
<?php

/* Namespace */
namespace Path\Foo\Bar;

/* Nome da classe deve ser o mesmo do arquivo */
class MyClass {
    public function e() {
        echo "OK";
    }
}
```

Porém, para um melhor gerenciamento de suas classes, recomendo o [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md)