# Quando eu uso uma classe de um determinado namespace, preciso usar require?

Tags: php, aplicação-web

Eu estava dando uma estudada em algumas funcionalidades do PHP, então acabei me deparando com algo que me gerou curiosidade.

Ao utilizar namespace acabei tendo que fazer algo semelhante a isso:

```
use Model\User\Create
require 'User.php' //Arquivo onde se encontra a classe Create
```

Minha dúvida é em relação ao require, por exemplo, toda vez que eu utilizar namespace terei que fazer o require do arquivo onde as classes se encontram, ou apenas tenho que fazer isso quando não estou utilizando autoload?

Comment: Relacionada: [Novo autoload do PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/250949/novo-autoload-do-php-7)

Comment: Relacionada: [Dúvidas sobre o autoload PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/266609)

Comment: Relacionada: [Como configurar o autoload no composer?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/287689/como-configurar-autoload-composer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... toda vez que eu utilizar `namespace` terei que fazer o require do arquivo onde as classes se encontram, ou apenas tenho que fazer isso quando não estou utilizando autoload?

Você só tem que usar as funções `require`, `require_once`, `include` e `include_once` para classes quando você não tem um sistema de autoload para elas. E não só para caso dos namespaces, mas as classes sem `namespace` também.

Creio que o autoload surgiu justamente para resolver esse problema. Se você tiver muitas classes no projeto, além de configurar os `namespace`, você teria que incluir uma por uma com `require`.

Para não ter problemas com isso, você pode usar o [autoload do composer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/287689/como-configurar-autoload-composer) ou a função `spl_autoload_register`.

Veja um exemplo:

```php
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {

    $path  = 'src/' . str_replace("\\", "/", $class) . '.php';

    if (file_exists($path)) require_once $path;
});
```

Comment: Show, muito obrigado! É, foi justamente isso que eu meio que tinha pensado, pq no meu caso era apenas uma classe, mas em grandes projetos seria uma mão ter que fazer o require a todo instante. Conseguiu responder minha dúvida, vlwzão mesmo.